# How can I 'bridge' and unbridge connections between two inputs

Tags: button

How can I make a non physical switch so that when in one state the two wires will be connected and in another they are not.
IE: Current going through into I/O 22 and being connected or not connected to a wire leading from I/O 23.
I am using a ardunio mega, and the code compiler is Ardunio as-well.

It is kinda like a no moving parts button, if you will.

Comment: We need to know the voltage involved and the power level to be able to answer well. Best of all, what are you trying to connect to what with your switch. Rather than play 100 guesses, if you tell us the actual problem we can tell you the actual answer.

Comment: This sounds very much like the wrong question.  Pop up two levels and explain *what* you are really trying to accomplish and not *how* you think it should be accomplished.  You are not qualified to decide the how quite yet.

Comment: @charles - The above comments are relevant - I answered the basic switch question as best I could, but I suspect if you explain *clearly* what you are actually trying to achieve we may able to let you know of a better way to do it. A rough diagram usually helps in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a non mechanical switch, then you need a multiplexer.

Something like [this](http://uk.farnell.com/nxp/74hc1g66gw-125/analog-switch-ic-single-spst-tssop/dp/1867069) for an analog signal should do.
To use the above, you just connect either side to Y and Z - they are like the switch terminals through which the signal passes (or not), your supply voltage to  Vcc, ground to GND. To switch you toggle the E input, which switches the "switch" on or off.

[image: 74HC1G66]

EDIT - [here](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/ts5a3167dbvr/ic-analog-sw-spst-sot23-5/dp/1755410) is another more expensive example part. This has a maximum ON resistance of 0.9 ohm (as opposed to up to 100 ohms for the cheaper part) 200MHz bandwidth and can handle up to 500mA.
It is used in a similar manner to that described for the other part.

This part below is now not relevant to the question but I'll leave it here for future reference.
If the signal is digital either the above or a tristate buffer gate could be used. If the signal doesn't go anywhere else you could just tristate the microcontroller pin.
For example you may not need this if your signal from I/O 23 does not go to anything else apart from I/O 22 (does it?) If this is the case why don't you just switch I/O 23 to high impedance (i.e. input) when you don't need it?  
If I/O 23 drives something else as well as I/O 22, or the signal is coming from somewhere else and both pins are inputs then you probably need the multiplexer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I use this device?

Comment: Also, the multiplexer is exactly the same as a button only non physical correct? My problem using a buffer gate is that the source of the current actually matters since I am running from one circuit to another and back and if it isn't passing the same current through then I get problems in the previous circuit. 
IE: I can't emulate the current with a I/O pin, but a button works.

Comment: @charleshorvath - the multiplexer will have a certain on resistance (typically below 100 ohms) so you need to take this into account, but there is no buffering going on, it just looks like a small resistor.

Comment: If the specs of the example part are not good enough, there are plenty of other options out there - I just picked a very cheap part. Other (usually) more expensive parts have e.g. lower ON resistance, can handle more current etc. Do a search for "multiplexer" or "analog switch" on any of the usual sites (e.g. Mouser, Farnell, etc) and you will get thousands to choose from. You can filter by things like maximum ON resistance to narrow things down.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I hope the 100 ohms resistance wont have a great effect.

Comment: What I have is two circuits (call them A and B) the Ardunio(A) and the separate one (B), B sends a five volt signal out and has another port which receives it and uses the information, the other port is wired in a way that the current being sent out HAS to be from the specific output, meaning I can't just send a five volt supple from my Ardunio to signal B. (So a buffer wont work) But I also need a nonphysical switch I can trigger with my Ardunio, which is exactly (as you say) what the multiplexer does.
Thanks!

Comment: Does a part like this work? http://uk.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/lm339ad/ic-comparator-quad-smd/dp/1467687

Comment: @charleshorvath - not for multiplexing, no. It's a comparator, which compares it's two analogue inputs and outputs high or low depending on whether one is higher/lower than the other. You can think of it like a 1-bit analogue to digital converter.

Comment: So I ordered a few of the cheaper parts(the more expensive ones where out of stock everywhere), and these parts are TINY. They are VERY VERY small, I don't have the proper equipment to make connections to them.